# Prove using mathematical induction that $x^{2n} - y^{2n}$ is divisible by $x+y$

Tags: induction

Prove using mathematical induction that 
 $(x^{2n} - y^{2n})$ is divisible by $(x+y)$.

**Step 1:** Proving that the equation is true for $n=1 $

$(x^{2\cdot 1} - y^{2\cdot 1})$ is divisible by $(x+y)$

**Step 2:** Taking $n=k$

$(x^{2k} - y^{2k})$ is divisible by $(x+y)$

**Step 3:** proving that the above equation is also true for $(k+1)$

$(x^{2k+2} - y^{2k+2})$ is divisible by $(x+y)$.

Can anyone assist me what would be the next step? Thank You in advance!

Comment: Not by induction: set $x+y=0$, then you have $x^{2n}-y^{2n}=0$. This is enough !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: putting $n=1$, we get $$x^{2n}-y^{2n}=x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$$ above number is divisible by $(x+y)$. Hence the statement is true $n=1$

step 2: assuming that for $n=m$,  $(x^{2n}-y^{2n})$ is divisible by $(x+y)$ then we have $$(x^{2m}-y^{2m})=k(x+y) \tag 1$$
Where, $k$ is an integer

step 3: putting $n=m+1$ we get $$x^{2(m+1)}-y^{2(m+1)}$$ $$=x^{2m+2}-y^{2m+2}$$
$$=x^{2m+2}-x^{2m}y^2-y^{2m+2}+x^{2m}y^2$$ $$=(x^{2m+2}-x^{2m}y^2)+(x^{2m}y^2-y^{2m+2})$$ $$=x^{2m}(x^2-y^2)+y^2(x^{2m}-y^{2m})$$ Setting the value of $(x^{2m}-y^{2m})$ from (1), we get $$x^{2m}(x-y)(x+y)+y^2k(x+y)$$ $$=k(x^{2m}(x-y)+y^2)(x+y)$$ It is clear that the above number is divisible by $(x+y)$. Hence the statement holds for $n=m+1$

Thus $(x^{2n}-y^{2n})$ is divisible by $(x+y)$ for all positive integers $\color{blue}{n\geq 1}$

Answer (score 11):

**Hint:** Rewrite:
$$x^{2k+2}-y^{2k+2}=(x^{2k+2}-y^{2k}x^2)+(y^{2k}x^2-y^{2k+2})=x^2(x^{2k}-y^{2k})+y^{2k}(x^2-y^2).$$

**Added:** Note it can be proved without induction:
$$x^{2n}-y^{2n}=(x^2)^n-(y^2)^n=(x^2-y^2)(x^{2(n-1)}+x^{2(n-2)}y^2+\dots+x^2y^{2(n-2)}+y^{2(n-1)}),$$
and the first factor is divisible by $x+y$.

Answer (score 4):

$$x^{2(k+1)}-y^{2(k+1)}=x^2x^{2k}-y^2y^{2k}=x^2x^{2k}\color{green}{-x^2y^{2k}+x^2y^{2k}}-y^2y^{2k}\\
=x^2(x^{2k}-y^{2k})+(x^2-y^2)y^{2k}.$$

The first term is divisible by $x+y$ by the induction hypothesis, and the second as well, by direct factorization.

Comment: why must we have that green part?

Comment: Because it allows the next step.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=k$, assume $P(k)$ is true, we have

$$x^{2k}-y^{2k}=A(x-y)$$, where A is a polynomial.

For $n=k+1$,

\begin{align}
x^{2k+2}-y^{k+2}&=x^2[A(x-y)+y^{2k}]-y^{2k+2}\\&=A(x-y)x^2+x^2y^{2k}-y^{2k+2}\\&=A(x-y)x^2+y^{2k}(x^2-y^2)\\&=A(x-y)x^2+y^{2k}(x-y)(x+y)\\&=(x-y)[Ax^2+y^{2k}(x+y)]\\&=B(x-y)\text{, where } B \text{ is a polynomial}.
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

When $n=1$,

$$x^{2n} - y^{2n} =x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$$

which is divisible by $(x+y)$. Assume true for $n=k$. Then $x^{2k}-y^{2k}$ is divisible by $x+y$.
Putting $n=k+1$,
$$x^{2n}-y^{2n}=x^{2k+2}-y^{2k+2}=\left(x^{k+1}-y^{k+1}\right) \left(x^{k+1}+y^{k+1}\right)$$

When $k$ is an odd number, $x+y$ is a factor of $x^{k+1}-y^{k+1}$.
Similarly, when $k$ is an even number, $x+y$ is a factor of $x^{k+1} + y^{k+1}$.
Hence $x^{2n}-y^{2n}$ is divisible by $x+y$ for integers $n>0$.