# Adding and subtracting a value in proofs

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

In most of the solutions for [Prove using mathematical induction that $x^{2n} - y^{2n}$ is divisible by $x+y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377927/prove-using-mathematical-induction-that-x2n-y2n-is-divisible-by-xy?newreg=f70e9543fc994385af204f31b04480ce) there is a line in which the value $x^{2m}y^2$ is added and subtracted from the equation.

Thereafter the equation is split into two binomials and so on...What is the intuition behind the value $x^{2m}y^2$?

Is there any hueristic for adding 0 in a proof (i.e. adding and subtracting a value)?

Comment: Search for "adding zero creatively". It is very helpful in various areas like factorization.

Comment: The famous nutritious null ...